# margin: auto is not centering

Tags: css

In the following style from the website: http://6.470.scripts.mit.edu/css_exercises/exercise4.html

```
<style type="text/css">
  #sponsors {
         margin:auto;
         margin-top:50px;
         overflow: hidden;
         width: auto;
         display: inline-block;
  }
  div.image img {
         margin: 3px;
         border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  }
  div.image a:hover img {
        border: 1px solid;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Sponsors of 6.470</h1>
 <div id="sponsors">
   <div class="image"><a href=""><img src="images/appian.png" width="150" height="85"></a></div>
   <div class="image"><a href=""><img src="images/dropbox.png" width="150px" height="85px"></a></div>
   <div class="image"><a href=""><img src="images/facebook.png" width="150px" height="85px"></a></div>
   <div class="image"><a href=""><img src="images/nextjump.png" width="150px" height="85px"></a></div>
   <div class="image"><a href=""><img src="images/palantir.png" width="150px" height="85px"></a></div>
   <div class="image"><a href=""><img src="images/quora.png" width="150px" height="85px"></a></div>
   <div class="image"><a href=""><img src="images/tripadvisor.png" width="150px" height="85px"></a></div>
   <div class="image"><a href=""><img src="images/vecna.png" width="150px" height="85px"></a></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

if the `width: auto` is removed from `#sponsors` then the `div#sponsors` is not center aligned even though `margin: auto` is used.

Similarly if instead of `text-align: center` is replaced by `margin: auto` in body style above, then the `<h1>` will not be center aligned which is preposterous;

because I have used `margin: auto` a lot of times and it was able to center the content without any issue. So hence help me and I will appreciate this a lot.

PS: I used firefox and besides use the `doctype` tag it is still not able to center with `margin: auto`.

Comment: The element with `id=sponsors` *is* centered. It just does not matter, since it has 100% width (as `div` elements have by default). You need to specify what exactly you wish to have centered and in which sense (what it should really look like).

Comment: see my answer i have added demo too

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Define `width` or `margin` on your `#sponsors` ID

as like this

```
#sponsors{
margin:0 auto; // left margin is auto, right margin is auto , top and bottom margin is 0 set
width:1000px; // define your width according to your design 
}
```

More about **[margin auto](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/centering-a-website/)**

Comment: Good. Everyone's answer seems to be correct. I select the first one as official answer.

Comment: Why does CSS width work, but if you set the width/height html attributes, it does not work?

Answer (score 3):

No need of using `margin: 0 auto`. Try the below code, it will work:

```
div#sponsors{
    /* other css properties */ 
    /* remove display:inline-block and margin: auto */       
    width:100%;  /* instead of width: auto */
    text-align: center;

}

div.img{
    /*remove float:left */
    /* other css properties */
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Remove `text-align: center` from `body` tag and give to `h1` tag instead.

Answer (score 2):

For centering `DIV` you need to set `css` for below.

**Example**

```
#sponsors {
   margin:0px auto;
}
```

**Comment**

You also need to set width for div.

#### **[`DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/JLryj/2/)**

Comment: Yes, you do. @DanielImms http://jsfiddle.net/JLryj/ versus http://jsfiddle.net/JLryj/1/

Comment: The question has `margin:auto;`. How would it be relevant to tune this?

Answer (score 2):

You must specify width to div and don't give margin twice

```
#sponsors {
    margin:50px auto 0 auto;
    margin-top:50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width:160px;
    background:aqua
 }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TL9Jn/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me!

```
.classofdiv{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TO use `margin:auto` you should use `position:relative`, oh, and define a `width`
Imagine you as a browser, how do you center a "box" (like div) if you don't know what is the width of that? ;)

I hope to help you

**correcting**: as Christopher Marshall said you don't need `position:relative` but specify width.

Comment: You don't need position:relative for centering using margin.

Comment: yep, I'm wrong about `position`, I rushed to mention it, usually I define `position:relative` for all element with my css reset,

Answer (score 0):

```
div{
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #ddd; 
    width:150px; 
    height:50px;
    margin: auto;
    /*position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;*/
}
img.displayed {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;

}

<html>
<div >
 <a>
 <img class="displayed" src="smiley.gif" >
 </a>
</div>
</html>
```

[demo added in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JLryj/96/)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look, maybe you have there a **float** property. In my case, setting **float** to **none** helps. Now div is properly aligned.

Answer (score 0):

margin: auto doesn't put the element in center if width of element is 100%. So give some width to element and use margin: auto. It worked for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30721679)

Answer (score -1):

If any div u want in center for margin auto always this div width is fix ......

```
#sponsors {
width:XXpx;
margin:50px auto 0;
overflow: hidden;
display: inline-block;
 }
```

Comment: You're overriding your first margin with your second call, that's unnecessary.