# How to move checkboxes to the center in a table cell

Tags: html, css, checkbox, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-table

I'm working on this simple table for bootstrap and I don't have really any experience with bootstrap and/or css. I need these checkboxes to be in the center of their column, but the problem is they stay on the far left. I put css (with `<style>` ) to create a custom class and set `float: none`, just to see if that would help, but it didn't. And since it's checkboxes, text-align doesn't help much.

Here's an image:
[image: tableImage]

And here's the HTML:

```
<tr id="emailDiv" style="display: none">
    <td style="white-space: nowrap; width: 30%"><span id="emaillabel">Email Label</td>
    <td style="width: 5%">
        <input type="button" value="Edit" id="emailAlert" class="btn btn-default btn-block-mobile btn-xs" />
    </td>
    <td class="text-center" style="width: 8%">
        <input type="checkbox" class="sub-col-1 dont-get-data" data-billaccount="emailField" data-subtype="15" />
    </td>
    <td style="width: 8%">
        <input type="checkbox" class="sub-col-2 dont-get-data" data-billaccount="emailField" data-subtype="16" />
    </td>
    <td style="width: 8%">
        <input type="checkbox" class="sub-col-3 dont-get-data" data-billaccount="emailField" data-subtype="17" />
    </td>
    <td style="width: 8%">
        <input type="checkbox" class="sub-col-4 dont-get-data" data-billaccount="emailField" data-subtype="18" />
    </td>
    <td style="width: 8%">
        <input type="checkbox" class="sub-col-5 dont-get-data" data-billaccount="emailField" data-subtype="19" />
    </td>
    <td style="width: 8%">
        <input type="checkbox" class="sub-col-6 dont-get-data" data-billaccount="emailField" data-subtype="20" />
    </td>
    <td style="width: 8%">
        <input type="checkbox" class="sub-col-7 dont-get-data" data-billaccount="emailField" data-subtype="21" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Try adding the `m-auto` class to the `input` elements.

Comment: I'm appauled by the overall quality of the multitude of answers here

Comment: @Martin Lol yeah, I was like "Oh crap, am I in the wrong area?". Tagged it with Bootstrap for more specificity.

Comment: @EdwardSeverinsen we don't know what version of Bootstrap it is, the OP should really inform us `;-)` (hint!)

Comment: @Martin Sorry, I'm still working on the issue. Bootstrap 3.0.0. I've tried all the proposed solutions, and none of them have fixed my problem. It's making me start to wonder if I accidentally missed something fundamental that's preventing the solutions from working. One answer had code to prove it, and that answer didn't work either.

Comment: @Josh do you have the webpage online we can look at directly?

Comment: @Martin Sorry, I'm working on updating an application at my place of work. So I'm hosting it locally during the development process (Visual Studio is the IDE). It won't be public till the whole massive project is finished.

Comment: @Josh Google Firefox Developer Toolkit (Element Inspector). It will be invaluable in solving your issue because you can apply changes directly to the page in the browser and see what works . (There are also similar ones for Google Chrome and others)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me. Thanks to everyone who answered, this community wouldn't be what it is without you awesome people.

```
td input[type="checkbox"] {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Credit goes to this guy.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20042250/4526963

Answer (score 1):

This would work.

Inline style

```
<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;">
    <input type="checkbox"> 
</td>
```

But its good if you use a class

CSS:

```
 .center-check-box{
    text-align:center; 
    vertical-align:middle;
 }
```

HTML:

```
 <td class="center-check-box">
    <input type="checkbox"> 
 </td>
```

Comment: Why not, It would be better if he writes inside a class. Just for his clarification only, I used inline style;.

Answer (score 1):

You can use css class

```css
.myCheckbox {
  text-align : center;
  border: 1px solid red; /* for illustration only */
  width:125px; /* for illustration only */
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td class="myCheckbox">
  <input type="checkbox">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If this can be put into a `.class` or `#id` this would be the first good answer here

Comment: `.class`es (or `#id`s) are always better and recommended over inline styles

Comment: I would also recommend using the table structure as in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your css

```
input[type='checkbox'] {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: This only works if the element (and its parent) is a certain display type - [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15697830/margin-auto-is-not-centering)

Comment: @Martin I found the answer on another question. `margin: 0 auto` was apart of it, but didn't fix it by itself. Thanks for your help man.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead
CSS

```
 input[type='checkbox'] { 
       vertical-align: center; 
 }
```

Comment: Hello. I have formatted your answer please take a look and see how to format `code`  display. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

> I'm working on this simple table for bootstrap

Try adding the Bootstrap `m-auto` class to the `input` elements.